# How can I breed a Solstice Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I hear there's a limited-time Solstice Dragon that looks like the Sun Dragon for the Summer Solstice. There was no in-game update referencing the dragon at all.

How can I breed a Solstice Dragon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Dragonvale Wiki entry on Solstice Dragon:](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Solstice_Dragon)

> The Solstice Dragon can be bred by selecting an **Earth or earth hybrid dragon to mate with a [Blazing Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Blazing_Dragon)** at the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.
>
> Solstice Dragon may also be bred using Sun and Solstice Dragon which has roughly a 50% chance of the result being a Solstice Dragon.

The breeding time for a Solstice Dragon is 23.5 hours. Note you'll need a Sun habitat to hatch one, they are Sun elemental. According to the [Dragonvale Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/dragonvale)They will remain until June 27. It's suggested by BackFlip that it's easier to get one during the day of the solstice (that's **June 20th** for the summer solstice). It will keep returning during the winter and summer solstices.

Note that the Sun/Solstice pairing has a higher chance of getting you a Solstice Dragon, but the breeding times will be much longer for failures. Also, due to the requirements of a Blazing Dragon, **you'll need to be level 14** in order to breed the prerequisite dragons.